# Python type error between list and int

Tags: python-3.x

Below is some code borrowed from another researcher who was investigating a similar problem to the one I'm trying to solve. In essence, I'm importing 3 variables -- x, mjo_amp and mjo_phase. I calculate mean values of x for each MJO phase (mjo_phase), rejecting any values where mjo_amp is less than 1. The function then reorders the data in an attempt to run a version of monte carlo simulations and test for statistical significance.

I got the following error when running the code:

```
>>> pprint( mjo_comp(x, mjo_amp, mjo_phase) )
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
pprint( mjo_comp(x, mjo_amp, mjo_phase) )
File "<pyshell#13>", line 36, in mjo_comp
tt = (mjo_phase==ph) * (mjo_amp>=1)
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

I imported my data like this:

```
import pandas
>>> colnames = ['x', 'mjo_phase', 'mjo_amp']
>>> data = pandas.read_csv('KBRO Daily Rainfall MJO Phase Simplified.csv', names = colnames)
>>> x = data.x.tolist()
>>> mjo_phase = data.mjo_phase.tolist()
>>> mjo_amp = data.mjo_amp.tolist()


def mjo_comp(x, mjo_amp, mjo_phase, N=1000, l0=50, L=1000, alpha=0.05, MCMC=True):
'''
Calculates composites of x based on MJO phase and amplitude.  Divides the
MJO into 8 phases and rejects all points for MJO amplitude less than 1
    phases = vector from 1 to 8
    x_mjo  = composites of x with 8 mjo phases
If MCMC = True then also performs a statistical significance test by
generating N randomly shuffled MJO phase vectors and recalculating the composite
results, returning a confidence interval corresponding to 1-alpha confidence.
'''
n = 8
count = np.zeros(n)
x_mjo = np.zeros(n)
x_mjo_mc = np.zeros((n,N))
phases = range(1,n+1)
#
for ph in phases:
    tt = (mjo_phase==ph) * (mjo_amp>=1)
    x_mjo[ph-1] = np.nanmean(x[tt])
    count[ph-1] = np.sum(tt)
#
if MCMC:
    for i in range(N):
        l = (l0+np.floor(np.random.rand(1)*L)).astype(int)[0]
        mjo_phase_mc = np.append(mjo_phase[l:], mjo_phase[:l])
        for ph in phases:
            tt = (mjo_phase_mc==ph) * (mjo_amp>=1)
            x_mjo_mc[ph-1,i] = np.nanmean(x[tt])
#
    x_mjo_95CI = np.percentile(x_mjo_mc, [100*alpha/2., 100*(1. - alpha/2.)], axis=1).T
else:
    x_mjo_95CI = None
#
return phases, x_mjo, count, x_mjo_95CI
```

Any idea of what's going wrong here? It seems as though the code may be expecting mjo_amp to be a single number, but I need to import that as a list, with mjo_amp being different for each data point.

Comment: You are comparing a list and an int with `mjo_amp >= 1`, which isn't supported by the comparison operator. You might want to reference a specific item with `moj_amp[item]`, where `item` is an index.

Comment: Thanks. The goal of that line is to loop through 8 separate 'MJO phases...i.e. ph=1,2,3...8. And then the idea is to store a series of 1s and 0s in the tt vector...where 1s represent the cases where a given phase has an amplitude >=1 and 0s are when the amplitude is <1 for a given phase. I'm a little confused on where I would reference mjo_amp as an index?

Comment: Will `moj_phase` and `moj_amp` always be arrays of the same length, and do they contain 8 data points? If they are, you can use `ph` from `for ph in phases:` to  to reference locations in `moj_phase[ph]` and `moj_amp[ph]`. If your arrays aren't eight items in length, you can follow a similar but modified approach of iterating over a range to provide a meaningful reference index.

Comment: Those arrays will always be the same length but will have hundreds of data points. mjo_phase will always be an integer ranging from 1-8 because those numbers are essentially a classification, if that makes sense. The values for mjo_amp are floats generally in the range of 0.5-2.5. The goal of the line in question is to eliminate data points where mjo_amp <1.

Comment: You might want a nested loop to check each element of `moj_phase` and `moj_amp`.